# How to use prepared statement for separated mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am little confuse how to use prepare statement in this. i tried but failed as my query is separated.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM report WHERE 1";

if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])){

 $name = $_GET['name'];

 $q .= " AND user ='$name'";
}

if(isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])){

 $category = $_GET['category'];

 $q .= " AND category ='$category'";        
}

$q .= " ORDER BY report.id desc LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
$all = $conn->query($q);
```

I have tried this but it messed up and dosenot work.

```
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM report WHERE 1");

if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])){

 $name = $_GET['name'];

 $q .= " AND user = ?";
}

if(isset($_GET['category']) && !empty($_GET['category'])){

 $category = $_GET['category'];

 $q .= " AND category = ?";        
}

$q .= " ORDER BY report.id desc LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
$q->bind_param('ss', $name, $category);
$q->execute();
$all = $q->get_result();
```

Comment: _"as prepare statement can execute only one query at a time"_ - you are not trying to execute more than one statement at a time here, so why would that be an issue?

Comment: based on if else parameters can be less or more as per my thinking

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie there are more ifs. i just skip them to short the code out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd code it using a prepared statement (using PDO):

```
$terms = [];
$params = [];

if($user = $_GET['name'] ?? null) {
  $terms[] = "user = ?";
  $params[] = $user;
}

if($category = $_GET['category'] ?? null) {
  $terms[] = "category = ?";
  $params[] = $category;
}

$where = '';

if ($terms) {
  $where = "WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $terms);
}

$q = "SELECT * FROM report $where 
  ORDER BY report.id desc 
  LIMIT $no_of_records_per_page OFFSET $offset";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($q);

$stmt->execute($params);
```

I assume `$offset` and `$no_of_records_per_page` are not from an unsafe source. If they are set using literals in your code, they're safe to use directly in the query.

---

Re your comment:

PHP's `[]` operator can add just *one* element to the array. If the thing you add is an array, that becomes a nested array.

You can append multiple elements to the array in a couple of ways. Either one at a time:

```
$params[] = $from_date;
$params[] = $to_date;
```

Or use builtin array functions, like either of these solutions:

```
$params = array_push($params, $from_date, $to_date);

$params = array_merge($params, [$from_date, $to_date]);
```

Or in PHP 7.4 and later, you can combine arrays this way:

```
$params = [...$params, $from_date, $to_date];
```

Comment: could you please explain why you initialized $terms, $params as array? as name and category is not necessarily array. and those two ?? before null

Comment: @Tanvir When, as in this case, you have a variable number of items, arrays make it easier to handle. `??` is a [PHP operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

Comment: Notice where I `implode()` the terms into an expression with ` AND ` between the terms. This works if the array of terms has an unknown number of arguments. If there are zero terms, then I just don't need a WHERE clause. I don't have a start with `WHERE 1`, which I always thought was a clumsy trick.

Comment: `??` is the "coalesce operator" introduced in PHP 7 (circa 2015). It returns the left argument if that's set, and if not, it returns the right argument.

Comment: `$params` is an array because that makes it easy to pass to `PDOStatement::execute()`.

Comment: `if($from_date = $_GET['from_date'] ?? $to_date = $_GET['to_date'] ?? null) {
     $terms[] = "time BETWEEN ? AND ? + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
     $params[] = [$from_date, $to_date];
 }`

in this case getting error of Undefined variable $to_date and mysqli_stmt::execute(): Argument #1 ($params) must consist of exactly 2 elements, 1 present

Comment: You've added one element to the array, which is itself an array of two elements.

Comment: sorry i cant figure it out. there are two parameters needed for time between sql. how can i achieve this?